# git: update a php-script but keep own changes

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch, mergetool

I'm tracking my changes on a PHP-software with git. I have only a master branch and about 10 commits, the first commit was the original version 1.0 of the software.

Now I saw, that the owner of the PHP-software released version 1.1.

What is the best an easiest way for me, to update the software, but keep my own changes too  and merge them with git mergetool? Should I use patches or create another branch with the untouched version updates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical approach is to create a branch with local changes (say "local") on top of the software:

```
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b local
....edit files....
git commit
```

now whenever there is upstream update, you can easily reapply changes using rebase:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

If you already have some merge history in master branch, try doing it raw and use 'git diff' to produce a complete patch of your work against upstream -- such package can be simply applied even without git tools.

Comment: git rebase was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the `stash` for this. Just call `git stash`, pull the changes and run `git stash pop` which will reapply your stashed changes. Creating your own branch and merging it back after update is definitely the way too.